# How can I check if country occurs in string with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of movies and tv-series from Netflix, one of the columns is the countries where the show is available. This column contains strings that can have multiple countries in it (e.g.'Germany, Czech Republic').

Now I want to find all shows that is from a specific country. This means that I need to check if the country name appears in the string. I would like to solve it like this:

```py
df.loc[distinct_countries[0] in df['country']]
```

But pandas doesn't support the `in` operator. I did try to solve this by iterating over every country and movie but since the dataframe is quite large this solution is not efficient enough. If you know a simpler solution that uses pandas, feel free to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Series has an `.isin()` function.  Perhaps do some research on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). It can also handle *regular expressions* if you want to check for more than one country.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, the solution ended up being: ```df[df['country'].str.contains(distinct_countries[0])==True] ```